# Rule on changing a question after a bounty was raised

Tags: discussion, bounties

What is the rule on completely changing a question once a bounty has been raised ?

For instance: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334315/null-pointer-exception-while-searching-for-text-in-array) is a question for which a bounty was raised and I answered it. 
Now the question is [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18334315/revisions) to a completely different question and the answer is completely out of context. Now in a scenario with multiple answers/ and or very few days to award the bounty - if the question is changed then the thread becomes pretty irrelevant and the bounty pretty much becomes useless. Is this by design or is there a peer review for bounty question edits?

Comment: I feel like, in general, completely changing the question is (at very least) frowned upon

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Whoa I searched everything - but didnt think of looking up "chameleon questions" :) But shouldnt bounties be treated a little differently ?

Comment: The fact that it has a bounty doesn't really change the case. Users should not completely change a question. Especially not if that invalidates earlier answers.

Comment: What @Bart said. A bounty being on the question just puts a finer point on why, and adds extra fallout for when it happens.

Comment: Interestingly - now the question has been rolled back to its original state by a peer - what is the rule on that?

Comment: You could have rolled back too, Slartibartfast, when an edit invalidates existing answers. My "rule" was just: common sense. But I figured you were feeling a bit too much involved in this specific case, so I did it.

Comment: Haha thanks @Arjan , I just wanted to be clear on all the rules related to SO on this matter since there are quite a few of them :)

Comment: I really don't get why people do this in general. I mean, I guess in this case, the question had a bounty and he wanted to capitalize on that to the extent possible. But I see it all the time with questions I've answered, no bounty in sight. It is completely free to ask a new question, yet it seems like I'm constantly having to beg people to ask a new question rather than bug me in the comments of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine that the etiquette for changing a question after a bounty has been set are the same as the rules for changing the question if a bounty has not been set.

It's frowned upon.

Comment: In my community we are a happy people and frowning is not permitted. Our etiquette is to punch people like this, no exceptions. Which probably explains why we are such a happy people